# Icon sizes- Xamarin.forms

Tags: icons, xamarin.forms, splash-screen

I am working on Xmarin.forms project. I have many icons in the app. what should be the size of the icons for each platform? I know android supports

**Android**

```
72x72 - drawable
72x72 - drawable-hdpi
96x96 - drawable-xhdpi
144x144 - drawable-xxhdpi
```

**iOS**

```
57x57
114x114
120x120
72x72
144x144
76x76
152x152
28x28
58x58
50x50
100x100
40x40
80x80
512x512
1024x1021
```

This sizes are only for the logo icons? Or all the icons including toolbar icon and burger menu(using master details) has to follow this resolutions? And what size images I can use for splash screen for android,iOs and windows phone? 
And what are icon sizes for windows phone?

Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 5):

It depends per platform, per control.
The best would be to refer to the platform specific documentation about user interfaces.

You can find Apple's [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html).

The one for Android can be found [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons).

The Windows one  can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662924(v=vs.105).aspx).

Or have a look at [this aggregated site](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/) with all sizes and flavours in one place.

Also there are some generation tools, at least for the app icons, etc. For example have a look at [Make App Icon](http://makeappicon.com).

Last but not least; have a good look at how each platform handles icons and sizes. For iOS and Android it has to do with naming conventions or in which folder you put your icons. This is to support all resolutions out there.

Comment: Please don't just link to sources.  Citing your sources is fine, but you should provide the actual details in your answer.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 you're absolutely right! And I have done so since