# Why is the icon ouput in my toolbar so small xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I need to add a logo in the left corner of my toolbar, as you can see the output is really small.

How can I make it bigger? I tried different sizes without it working.

What I don't understand is that the logo to the right works perfectly fine, even if I add it to the left.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

**My toolbar code**

```
<TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Icon="logocnesst.png"></ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem></ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Calculette de bruit"/>
    <ToolbarItem Icon="logocalculette.png"></ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem Text=""></ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem Text="À propos" Order="Secondary"></ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Références" Order="Secondary"></ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Mentions légales" Order="Secondary"></ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Aide" Order="Secondary"></ToolbarItem>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Options" Order="Secondary"></ToolbarItem>
</TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: resize the png itself

Comment: @Jason i'll try but what would be ideal dimensions ? Thanks

Comment: if you have one image that works and one that doesn't, I would use the dimensions of the one that works

Comment: @Jason well i tried much bigger png size and the image doesn't change :/

Comment: The images of different sizes will be used for devices of different dimensions. The icon's size cannot be changed for the same device. Check the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36621308/icon-sizes-xamarin-forms You could use `TitleView` instead, it supports to define the size of the image.

Comment: @JarvanZhang-MSFT Thanks for reply, i think TitleView is the best choice here, my only problem is that i won't be able to have toolbaritem with a secondary order ( the 3 dots at the end) is there a way to have titleview + toolbaritems secondary (3 dots)

Comment: Try using the following code to achieve the function. `<ContentPage ...>
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Image Source="grid_" HeightRequest="35"/>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="item_1" Order="Secondary"/>
        <ToolbarItem Text="item_2" Order="Secondary"/>
        <ToolbarItem Text="item_3" Order="Secondary"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        ...
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>`

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to have titleview + toolbaritems secondary (3 dots)

Try using the following code to achieve the function.

```
<ContentPage ...>
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Image Source="grid_" HeightRequest="35"/>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="item_1" Order="Secondary"/>
        <ToolbarItem Text="item_2" Order="Secondary"/>
        <ToolbarItem Text="item_3" Order="Secondary"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        ...
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

See the screenshot:

[image]